# How can i extend a ext.net control?

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I want to extend the ext.net calendarPanel. I did it this way

```
public class ExtCalendarPanel : CalendarPanel
{
    ....
}
```

when I use it in my page like this

```
Html.X().Panel()
    .ID("Panel1")
    .Title("...")
    .Layout("border")
    .Region(Region.Center)
    .Cls("app-center")
    .Items(
        (new Ext.Net.MVC.Examples.Areas.Calendar_Overview.Controllers.ExtCalendarPanel())
             .ToBuilder()
             .ID("CalendarPanel1")
             ...
             ...);
```

I get an error

```
 CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ExtCalendarPanel' does not exist in the namespace 'Ext.Net.MVC.Examples.Areas.Calendar_Overview.Controllers' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I am new to ext.net, can someone tell me what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide [how to create Razor MVC helpers for custom Ext.NET controls](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27672).